# Understanding the angle in the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

The Gauss-Bonnet Theorem says that for a simply connected region $D$ on a surface, we have 
$$\int\int_D KdA+\int_{\partial D}k_g ds=\int_{\partial D}d\alpha$$
where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature, $k_g$ is the geodesic curvature, and $\alpha$ is defined to be the angle between the tangent direction of the path $\partial D$ and the basis vector $e_1$ in the orthonormal frame.

Then I want to apply it to a spherical surface, with $D$ a hemisphere.
Since for a sphere, the Gaussian curvature is constant $1/r^2$ everywhere, where $r$ the radius of the sphere, we have 
$$\int\int_D KdA=\frac{1}{r^2}2\pi r^2 =2\pi$$
and since the path $\partial D$ is the equator, which is a geodesic line, we have $k_g=0$ along $\partial D$, so the second integral vanishes. Then we have
$\int_{\partial D}d\alpha=2\pi$, which makes intuitive sense that along the equator our velocity (tangent vector) rotates a whole circle and should be $2\pi$. BUT, in my textbook the angle $\alpha$, as I have mentioned, is defined to be the angle between the tangent direction of the path $\partial D$ and the basis vector $e_1$ in the orthonormal frame, and on the equator, the two directions are the same! Then $\alpha$ is $0$ (or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ if you take another basis vector) everywhere along the path. Then why 
$$\int_{\partial D}d\alpha=2\pi$$
I think I didn't really get the definition of $\alpha$.

Comment: Is your purported orthonormal frame everywhere defined (and continuous) on the entire hemisphere? (Also see the discussion on pp. 82-83 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you so much for your comment (and your detailed text!) My textbook is rather sloppy when introducing orthogonal frame, so I just know that at every point on the surface we set up an orthonormal frame, but it never mentions continuity or something. I will read your textbook to aid my learning (and share it to my classmates). Thanks again!